# Why does MySQL not use index if varchar size is too high?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am joining with a table and noticed that if the field I join on has a varchar size that's too high then MySQL doesn't use the index for that field in the join, thus resulting in a significantly longer query time. I've put explains and table definition below. It is version MySQL 5.7. Any ideas why this is happening?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `LotRecordsRaw` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lotNumber` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `scrapingJobId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `lotNumber_UNIQUE` (`lotNumber`),
  KEY `idx_Lot_lotNumber` (`lotNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14551 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Explains:

```
explain
(
  select lotRecord.*
  from LotRecordsRaw lotRecord
  left join (
    select lotNumber, max(scrapingJobId) as id
    from LotRecordsRaw
    group by lotNumber
  ) latestJob on latestJob.lotNumber = lotRecord.lotNumber
)
```

produces:
[image]

The screenshot above shows that the derived table is not using the index on "lotNumber". In that example, the "lotNumber" field was a varchar(255). If I change it to be a smaller size, e.g. varchar(45), then the explain query produces this:

[image]

The query then runs orders of magnitude faster (2 seconds instead of 100 sec). What's going on here?

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the exact definitions of both tables. And please mention the MySQL version you use.

Comment: @Bohemian Not sure how to do that with the output in MySQL workbench, otherwise I would have. Thanks

Comment: There is no reason to create indices duplicates. Remove `idx_Lot_lotNumber`, it is excess. When you define the column as unique then unique index is created. Check what is critical size - i.e. on what precise length the server stops index using. I predict that it is ~ 190.. PS. 1st explain matches not 255 but 250..

Comment: @AlexLong don't use workbench. Workbench has nothing to do with the problem. Use CLI and copy-paste the output.

Comment: @Bohemian Ah, I had forgotten about the CLI as an option, I'll do that next time, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hooray!  You found an optimization reason for not blindly using 255 in `VARCHAR`.

Please try 191 and 192 -- I want to know if that is the cutoff.

Meanwhile, I have some other comments:

- A `UNIQUE` is a `KEY`.  That is, `idx_Lot_lotNumber` is redundant and may as well be removed.
- The Optimizer can (and probably would) use `INDEX(lotNumber, scrapingJobId)` as a much faster way to find those MAXes.
- Unfortunately, there is no way to specify "make a *unique* index on lotNumber, but also have that other column in the index.
- Wait!  With `lotNumber` being unique, there is only one row per lotNumber.  That means `MAX` and `GROUP BY` are totally unnecessary!
- It seems like `lotNumber` could be promoted to `PRIMARY KEY` (and completely get rid of `id`).

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your response. I did some more testing of the varchar size and it looks like 250 is where it stops using the index. I tested 191, 192, 220, 235, 240, 245-249 and they all used the index. Do you happen to know why this is happening? Or is there some doc you could point to referencing this behavior? Happy to mark your excellent answer as accepted but would be great to get a little more insight into why this is happening for future situations. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexLong - Ooooo, that's interesting.  250 * 4 (size of utf8mb4) = 1000.  But I have seen 1000 only in relation to MyISAM; you are using InnoDB.  (http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits) I'm eager to find the answer to this, but I don't know where to look next.  You could try bugs.mysql.com -- which reaches the Oracle developers or jira.mariadb.com for the MariaDB devs.